# Tensorflow taking input in the same order as input

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow to test my trained model on test images. I am feeding the images to tensorflow as below:

```
image_ab, image_aba = sess.run(fetches, feed_dict={self.image_a: image_a,
                                               self.is_train: False})
```

I printed the `image_a` and `image_ab` and observed that `image_a` is not in the same order as the input images i give.

For some reasons i want the output also to be in the same order as input images.

Does tensorflow usually takes input in the same order as the input given?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `image_ab` is not in the same order. Because `image_a` is the input that you feed to tensorflow. If this input is not ordered correctly, it will be your preprocessing, not tensorflow.

Tensorflow usually works on batches of data. For images, the convention for batch dimensions is:

```
[batch, x, y, colors]
```

The operations that tensorflow performs are parallelized along the batch. If you simply plug convolutional layers together, the order of the batch should be preserved.

However, it is surely possible to reorder things in tensorflow:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(shape=(2,1), dtype="float32")
y = tf.concat([x[1], x[0]], axis=0)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([x,y], feed_dict={x:np.random.rand(2,1)})
```

This code will read in x, change the order of its entries and produce y.
So tensorflow can reorder your images. You could search your code for a pattern like the one in my example.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.. I am aware of the same so i checked and indeed saved the image_a just before feeding to check the order and is perfectly fine with the input image order.